# Awful page breaking when very long multicolumns items are used

Tags: tables, page-breaking, multicolumn

I am using `ltablex` with `\multicolumn`s. My problem is that I have to introduce a lot of text inside of single `\multicolumn` items, then when it automatically breaks the table on two different pages, it remains a lot of white space at the end of the first page. I would like to find a clue for automatically breaking a `\multicolumn` item when the bottom margin is reached, instead of breaking on a row-by-row basis. Here is an example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |}
blabla & more blabla & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{merging cells} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{more merging} \\
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule}|}{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule}|}{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule}|}{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule}|}{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, } \\
\hline
...
\multicolumn{8}{|p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule}|}{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, } \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: So you want to have a cell (your `\multicolumn`) break in a middle from one page to the next? Current that capability does not exist, unless you switch to using lists. Looking at your code snippet, this may be possible, since you're using a `\multicolumn` that spans the entire width of your `tabularx`.

Comment: Yes, I want to have a cell break in a middle from one page to the other one. Could you tell me more details about your proposed solution. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need at all to have a `longtable/ltablex` here (nor to use tabularx X columns.)
If you use `tabularx` tex  goes to a lot of effort re-setting the table and determining optimum column widths but you know in advance that the spanning cells are full width and the individual cells are an eighth of that (or at lesat a seventh of the linewidth minus the largest entry in the first column). So you can tell TeX that and save it the bother of working it out. Having fixed the cell widths they no longer need to be in the same table as they will line up anyway so you can replace the spanning entries by normal text. If you really need the vertical rules you could use `mdframed` to have a breakable frame.

note

```
\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule
```

isn't the right calculation as the rule width is `\arrayrulewidth` not `\fboxrule` (these might have the same value of course).

So something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textheight{-30\baselineskip}
\addtolength\paperheight{-30\baselineskip}
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\newenvironment{trow}
{\par
\begin{tabular}{|*8{p{\dimexpr(((\textwidth-\arrayrulewidth)/8)-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)\relax}|}}
\hline}
{\\\hline\end{tabular}%
\par}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\def\x{a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long
text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very
long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a
very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long text,
a very long text, a very long text, a very long text, a very long
text, a very long text, a very long text, }

\x
\begin{trow}
red&yellow&blue&green&red&yellow&blue&green
\end{trow}
\begin{trow}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8
\end{trow}

\x
\begin{trow}
red&yellow&blue&green&red&yellow&blue&green
\end{trow}
\begin{trow}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8
\end{trow}

\x
\begin{trow}
red&yellow&blue&green&red&yellow&blue&green
\end{trow}
\begin{trow}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8
\end{trow}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I need the ltablex environment. My table also have rows such as: blabla & more blabla & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{merging cells} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{more merging}. I have to edit my original post...sorry.

Comment: @user28939 You can use `\multicolumn` entries in the code I gave.

Comment: But in this case, the "rows" with long text are not framed by vertical lines, i.e. they are outside of the table.

Comment: as I said in the answer, you can do the outer frame with `mdframed` if you want to put the outer vertical lines back.